# Splitting a timestamp in the middle of a line

Tags: python, perl, bash, sed, awk

I've got a log file containing lines like this:

```
06/28/12 14:17:10.**754117** :R: INFO  [6] X10.cpp:4042 |xevent 35932825 1 0 0
```

I want that timestamp to split out the microseconds - i.e. I want the output to be of form:

```
06/28/12 14:17:10.**754 117** :R: INFO  [6] X10.cpp:4042 |xevent 35932825 1 0 0
```

How would I go about doing this?

I'm fine with using any standard UNIX tool (e.g. awk / sed) and python / perl.

Comment: Are the asterisks literally in the data or are you only using them to highlight the portion of interest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the asterisks are simply highlight for the purposes of the question and that they don't actually appear in the data:

```
echo '06/28/12 14:17:10.754117 :R: INFO  [6] X10.cpp:4042 |xevent 35932825 1 0 0' | 
awk '{$2 = substr($2, 1, length($2) - 3) " " substr($2, length($2) - 2); print}'
```

Results in:

```
06/28/12 14:17:10.754 117 :R: INFO [6] X10.cpp:4042 |xevent 35932825 1 0 0
```

You can also hardcode the lengths:

```
awk '{$2 = substr($2, 1, 12) " " substr($2, 13); print}'
```

Answer (score 2):

using just `sed`, match the first two stars (`*`) and the next three numbers and place a space after those. simple:

```
sed 's;\*\*[0-9]\{3\};& ;'
```

try it

```
$ echo '06/28/12 14:17:10.**754117** :R: INFO  [6] X10.cpp:4042 |xevent 35932825 1 0 0' | sed 's;\*\*[0-9]\{3\};& ;'
06/28/12 14:17:10.**754 117** :R: INFO  [6] X10.cpp:4042 |xevent 35932825 1 0 0
```

---

concerning @DennisWilliamson comment and answer, I'm not sure myself whether the stars there are part of the string, or where supposed to be part of markdown.
In any case, the only place where a `.XXX` (dot and three digits) will be matched is the ms part. so this would work too:

```
sed 's;[0-9]\{3\};& ;'
```

try it :)

```
$ echo '06/28/12 14:17:10.754117 :R: INFO  [6] X10.cpp:4042 |xevent 35932825 1 0 0' | sed 's;[0-9]\{3\};& ;'
06/28/12 14:17:10.754 117 :R: INFO  [6] X10.cpp:4042 |xevent 35932825 1 0 0
```

adding the dot would make it a bit safer:

```
sed 's;\.[0-9]\{3\};& ;'
```

try it :)

```
$ echo '06/28/12 14:17:10.754117 :R: INFO  [6] X10.cpp:4042 |xevent 35932825 1 0 0' | sed 's;\.[0-9]\{3\};& ;'
06/28/12 14:17:10.754 117 :R: INFO  [6] X10.cpp:4042 |xevent 35932825 1 0 0
```

Comment: This seems to me the most concise and elegant way to do this out of the answers here!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '06/28/12 14:17:10.**754117** :R: INFO  [6] X10.cpp:4042 |xevent 35932825 1 0 0' | \
sed 's/\(\*\*[0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]\{3\}\*\*\)/\1 \2/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression substitution with back-references in any of the tools you mentioned.

Replace: `'\*\*(\d{3})(\d{3})\*\*'`

with: `'\1 \2'`

(use `'$1 $2'` in Perl)

Comment: I should have added that you need to use the `-E` option with `sed` (for extended regular expressions, which `awk`, `Perl`, and `Python` all use)

Comment: Do you mean `-r` option? There is no `-E` option is `sed`.

Comment: @cdarke, Rush is correct, `sed` has `-r`, `grep` though has `-E` :) There is no need for extended regexes for this one, there is not even need for `\1` `\2` backreferences, just use `&`, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex
(in python)

```
import re

text = '06/28/12 14:17:10.**754117** :R: INFO  [6] X10.cpp:4042 |xevent 35932825 1 0 0'

def repl(m):
    return '**%s %s**' % (m.group(1)[:3], m.group(1)[3:])

re.sub('\*\*(\d{6})\*\*', repl, text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace in the file, and create a backup with the extention .bak

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/(\*\*\d{3})(\d{3}\*\*)/$1 $2/' filename
```